# Are there showers / sleeping facilities at SFO?

Tags: hygiene, sleeping, sfo

Odds are good I'll be sleeping in SFO in a couple of weeks' time, before a flight to YVR, upon which I'll go directly to work.

Not wanting to look too dishevelled, and not generally trusting myself to get up for flights at that time in a hotel, is there:

a) suggestions on where to sleep there?
b) public showers? (not in club lounges)

Comment: There needs to be a database of this kind of thing for airports all over the world...

Comment: @NateEldredge valid point, have adjusted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Sleepinginairports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/sanfrancisco.htm):

> **Showers** - Location: Freshen' Up International Terminal - landside, level G, Main Hall. Hours: 7:00am - 11:00pm. Fee: $15 for the Deluxe
>   Shower (30 minute shower + 15 minute massage chair with towel, soap,
>   shampoo, lotion, shower shoes, and a hairdryer if required) / $ 8 for
>   the Standard Shower (20 minute shower with soap and towel provided).
>
> **Sleeping** - Best sleeping spot Ive found so far is a lounge in Terminal 2 near Baggage Claim #4, with two padded benches each of
>   which is big enough for you and the one you love.

Answer (score 4):

[Sleeping In Airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/sanfrancisco.htm) has reviews from people regarding the best places to sleep.

The only public showers are at "Freshen Up" the international terminal.  From [the SFO website](http://www.flysfo.com/web/page/orphan/faq/index.html#11) :

> Shower facilities are available at Freshen Up! located on the
>   Departures/Ticketing Level of the International Terminal, near the
>   entrance to Gates G91-G102.  Freshen Up! is open daily from 7:00 a.m.
>   to 11:00 p.m.  For additional information call 650.877.0798.