# Free place to shower in San Francisco?

Tags: san-francisco, sfo

Well I sorta screwed up my itinerary flying out to California. I have a conference I'm attending for work in Santa Clara and I thought I'd fly into San Francisco instead of Santa Clara. Well, long story short, the friend I'm meeting in San Francisco can't meet up for a few hours after I get into San Francisco so, I should have just flown into Santa Clara, checked into my hotel, taken a shower and gone out to San Francisco for the rest of the day.

So, since I'm "stuck" (there are worse problems to have) with a couple of extra hours in San Francisco, is there a place I might be able to take a shower, brush my teeth and freshen up before playing tourist for the day?

Comment: Related (old but apparently still accurate): [Are there showers / sleeping facilities at SFO?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/are-there-showers-sleeping-facilities-at-sfo)

Comment: Since you're looking for free, do you have any high-end credit cards or elite frequent flyer?

Answer (score 5):

If you're flying into SFO, there is a business called [Freshen Up](https://www.flysfo.com/content/showers) in the airport. It won't be free, but [for $25](http://www.airporttravelagency.org/freshen-up/) you can, well, freshen up before you head into the city (sadly, their shorter cheaper option seems to be gone, at least from this price list).

Many local gyms will have shower facilities and sell day passes. This will likely cost you around the same as Freshen Up, but could be worth it if you're interested in working out too. I can point you to one if you have a specific neighborhood in mind.

Limited free shower facilities in San Francisco do exist, but are really intended as services for homeless people rather than travelers. If you're just looking to brush your teeth and splash some water on your face, that can be done at the airport or local malls or hotel restrooms.

Answer (score 4):

One cheap option would be to visit a public swimming pool, like the [Mission Community Pool](http://sfrecpark.org/destination/mission-playground/mission-community-pool/), for $6. Hours are more limited than a for-profit business.